# How to force Internet Explorer to refresh the list of options of a HTML select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html-select

I'm programmatically changing the `option` children of a `select` element with jQuery.

The changes are being applied to the DOM, but are not visible on the screen.

This is what I get on the screen:

[image: Combo box with 4 options]

And this is what I see when I inspect the `select` element:

[image: Html select with 5 option children]

Here is the code that I use to update the `select` element:

```
    select.empty();
    $.each(this.entries, function() {
        var option = $$("<option/>");
        option.attr("value", this.value);
        option.text(this.label);
        select.append(option);
    });
```

This clearly seems like a bug to me. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this or indicate a workaround ?

Note: for reasons beyond my control, the page is in quirks mode.

Comment: I think you need to use `selectElement.options.add(new Option("Name", "Value"))`

Comment: @Shmiddty It works, that you very much. I've been pulling my hair off my head for quite a long time... You may move that to an answer to earn the monkey money ;=)

Comment: `$$("<option/>");` should be `$("<option/>");`

Comment: Just a quick note about the $$: in my context, jQuery is $$, not $ which is an old proprietary API used in a lot of places. We do `(function($$, undefined){})(jQuery)` But I edited the source file to use widely use conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the SelectElement is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement

You can add options like this:

```
$("#sel")[0].options.add(new Option("test", "123")); //haven't tested all browsers
```

The docs say that you call `add` on the select element itself, passing in an option node:

```
$("#sel")[0].add($("<option>").val("456").prop("text", "Test2")[0], null);
```

both tested (and working) in IE8 here: http://jsfiddle.net/82gCq/2/

**Note** — The docs for [HTMLOptionsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLOptionsCollection) does not specify an `add` method, so it is not standardized, and its implementation will be left to the browser (if they implement it at all).

The good news is that `$("#sel")[0].add(new Option("test3", "789"));` works in IE8, and should work in other browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var option = $$("<option/>");
```

to

```
var option = $("<option></option>");
```

I removed the double dollar sign (I believe that was a typo), and changed the `option` element to not use the self-closing syntax. I've run into issues using self-closing tags on certain elements (`script`,`textarea`,`iframe`), this could be another example of where a self-closing tag could be a problem.